# copying all the .tar and .tar.bz2 file systems from all the sub-directories into another directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Imagine that i have lots of sub-directory in a sub-directory in a directory I wanted to copy all the .tar and .tar.bz2 extension files from all the sub-directories into another directory.

I used

```
$find /home/apple/mango -name *.tar -exec cp {} ./kk \;
```

but it copies only once from a sub directory and stops , it doesn't find files which are in other sub directories or go inside a sub directories and find them.
I want to do it recursively

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
find /home/apple/mango -name '*.tar*' -execdir cp {} /full/path/to/kk \;
```

Note how name pattern is quoted to avoid shell expansion even before `find` command executes.

In the absence of quoting `*.tar` is expanded to some `file.tar` which is present in current directory and `find` stop right there because `file.tar` is not found in sub directories. By quoting glob pattern we make sure that `find` command gets literal pattern to search the sub directories.